# MongoDB, NodeJs, отличия проекции поиска в разных версиях

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Добрый день! Есть такая строка запроса

```
collection.find({article:20}, {_id:0, article:1, name:1}).toArray((err, result)=>{
    console.log(result);
});
```

В версии MongoDB 2.6 (модуль для NodeJS версии 2.2 ) запрос возвращает ожидаемый результат.

В версии MongoDB 3.0 (модуль для NodeJS версии 3.0 ) запрос возвращает полностью весь документ. На изменение параметров проекции никак не реагирует, как-будто их нет вообще. В документации на эту тему ничего найти не смог. https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Кто знает в чем дело?

П.С.: если сделать аналогичный запрос с проекцией, через консоль, то все нормально отрабатывает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разобрался. В модуле MongoDB для NodeJs версии 3.0 изменился синтаксис подобного запроса. Теперь, вторым параметром в запросе, идет объект с различными опциями. Теперь запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
collection.find({article:20}, {projection:{_id:0, article:1, name:1}}).toArray((err, result)=>{
    console.log(result);
});
```