# Не могу достать данные из mongoDB

Tags: node.js, vue.js, mongodb, nuxt.js

Всем привет.
Хочу с фронта взять данные из БД. Получаю повисшый(pending) промис. Но я не понимаю где он. Метод .find() возвращает спец объект, а не промис. Или мне обернуть его в промис и вызывать resolve? Честно говоря, мне кажется что на фронте это делается по другому и я тупо что-то напутал.

```
 let mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect(
      'mongodb+srv://d2207:password@cluster0-37he4.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
      {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}
    );

    let db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function() {
      console.log("mongodb are connected")
    });

db.collection.find(({}), {projection:{_id:0, title:1, price:1, img:1, description:1, originURL:1}})
  .toArray((err, result)=>{
  console.log(result);
});
    //let products = db.collection('TestProductCollection2').find();
    //console.log(products);
    //db.close();
```

ошибка

```
db.collection.find(({}), {projection:{_id:0, title:1, price:1, img:1, description:1, originURL:1}})
              ^

TypeError: db.collection.find is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\crud-nuxt2\store\products.js:13:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795658/mongodb-nodejs-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85 здесь есть пример кода

Comment: Кстати я когда добавлял .toArray() то получал ошибку что .toArray() не функция

Comment: Воспользовался твоим кодом как примером - TypeError: db.collection.find is not a function
получил ошибку

Comment: ну так к коллекции еще подключитбся надо `const collection = db.collection(collectionName)`